# trying to get the value from selected bar

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, shiny-server

I want to detect some information when the user clicks in a bar of a column highchart plot. I need to get the name  of the clicked bar,and use as a input
I am trying to get the value from bar chart to use as input in data frame to filter the data fram

//server.r

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")
legendClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('legendClicked', [this.name, event.target.visible]);}")


    df <- data_frame(
      name = c("Animals", "Fruits", "Cars"),
      y = c(5, 2, 4),
      drilldown = tolower(name)
    )
ds <- list.parse3(df)
    names(ds) <- NULL
    str(ds)
hc <- highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
      hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") %>%
      hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
      hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(
        series = list(
          boderWidth = 0,
          dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE),
          events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction) click function is using here to get the values from bar high chart
```

)
          ) %>%
          hc_add_series(
            name = input$canvasClicked[2],
            colorByPoint = TRUE,
            data = ds
          )

```
    dfanny <- data_frame(
      name = c("Cats","Dogs","Cows","Sheep","Pigs","Apple","Oranges","Toyota","Opel","Volkswage"),
      name1=c("Animals","Fruits", "Cars","Animals", "Fruits", "Cars","Animals", "Fruits", "Cars","Cars"),
      value = c(4,2,4, 3, 1, 2, 1,4, 2, 2)
      )%>%filter(name1==input$canvasClicked[2])
input$canvasClicked[2](not getting the selected value)
##here getting error Result must have length 10, not 0

    dfan<-data_frame(
      name=dfanny$name,
      value=dfanny$value
    )

    second_el_to_numeric <- function(ls){
      map(ls, function(x){
        x[[2]] <- as.numeric(x[[2]])
        x
      })
    }
    dsan <- second_el_to_numeric(list.parse2(dfan))
    hc <- hc %>%
      hc_drilldown(
        allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
        series = list(
          list(
            id = "fruits",
            data = dsan
          )))




    return(hc)
  })

})
```

//ui.r

```
fluidPage(
      h1("Highcharter EXAMPLE"),
      fluidRow(
        highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
    ))
```

Comment: still stuck any help

Comment: Providing a run-able example gets you help a lot quicker. Here is what you need to do in highcharts; http://jsfiddle.net/v9atpy8o/ So you should find some way to add those options in your app.

Comment: still not getting the clicked value

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no there are not any errors